# Create animated gif from a set of png images

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, png, gif, animated-gif

I'm trying to use ffpmeg to convert a list of png to a gif.

Running `C:\Users\Me\Art\Animations\wubz\output> dir` shows my files:

```
12/04/2020  16:48    <DIR>          ..
12/04/2020  16:45           136,706 wubz_0001.png
12/04/2020  16:45           136,180 wubz_0002.png
12/04/2020  16:45           136,413 wubz_0003.png
12/04/2020  16:45           136,099 wubz_0004.png
12/04/2020  16:45           136,309 wubz_0005.png
12/04/2020  16:45           137,172 wubz_0006.png
```

The code I'm running in command prompt from `C:\Users\Me\Art\Animations\wubz\output>`:

```
ffmpeg-f image2 -framerate 30 -i wubz_%d.png video.flv
```

gives the error message:
`[image2 @ 000001efd6c4bac0] Could find no file with path 'wubz_%d.png' and index in the range 0-4
wubz_%d.png: No such file or directory`

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong, I don't get why ffmpeg isn't seeing the png files in the output directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the names have 4 numerals with leading zeros, the pattern should be `wubz_%04d.png`